# Is this some genius thing or simple just bad code?

Tags: java, template-engine

This is a code snippet I found in an open source Java templating project.

Does anyone have a clue what this construct may be good for?

```
  final public Expression Expression() throws ParseException {
   Expression exp;
    exp = OrExpression();
      {if (true) return exp;}
    throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");
  }
```

Comment: Quite a circumvoluted way to `return OrExpression();`

Comment: does `throw new Error()` is unreachable?

Comment: @assylias: exactly that's what I think too. I'm just wondering then why the hell the programmer write his/her code this way?

Comment: Is this an April's Fools joke?

Comment: This is generated code from an older version of JavaCC (prior to 6.1), and the generated code from this particular library can be convoluted. What is the name of the library where you found this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sloppy code. The actual effect is simply `return OrExpression();`.

There is one excuse that I accept for code like this: There are lots of other methods like it, which follow a similar pattern but are more complex such that the useless bits here are not useless. This is a bit of an extreme example, however.

**However**, there is almost no excuse for the `throw new Error("Missing return statement in function");`. The Java compiler will **refuse to compile** a method whose return type is not `void` and which has a code path which reaches the end (does not `return`, `throw`, or enter an infinite loop). The only reason this would be a good idea is if the intent was to *permit incomplete code to compile* — i.e. fail at run time rather than compile time so that other parts of the code can be used or tested — but even then applying it to all methods is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is an automatically generated code from JavaCC.